# Wrapped a working c++ application to run as a function in python but throws 200 errors

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have used `boost.python` to wrap a c++ application to eventually be able to call from python. I have done as the documentation suggests but I have just reached the stage where I have to build the solution on the cpp side. When I go to build the solution I get about 200 errors all stating stuff along the lines of `unresolved external symbol _imp_PyBytes` etc.

From what I can tell, all the unresolved external symbols have `py` in the name. This leads me to suggest there is a python issue during or after the build part of boost?

I have tried multiple different approaches to resolving this - from adding python library's directly into the include directories to rewriting the user-config.jam to rebuild boost.build

Here are some of the errors:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_PyBytes_AsString referenced in function "public: static class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl boost::python::converter::`anonymous namespace'::string_rvalue_from_python::extract(struct _object *)" (?extract@string_rvalue_from_python@?A0xea0695f0@converter@python@boost@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAU_object@@@Z) example C:\Users\frborden\source\repos\example\libboost_python37-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_71.lib(builtin_converters.obj)

I have about 200 errors similar to this one above. Most of the errors are linked to `libboost_python37-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_71.lib`

Any help would be massively appreciated. Hopefully I have provided enough information, but I am happy to respond to give more.

I am using Python 3.7 and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.3

Comment: Did you set library paths and libraries in your project? How do you build your project?

Comment: I have set library paths yes. I build it by rightclicking the solution and building?
@ThomasSablik

Comment: What solution? Are you using Visual Studio? You should describe it in your question.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I thought i mentioned I was using visual studio 2019 - will edit question